# Django form redirect

Tags: django, redirect

I have a form that and after the user fills in this form, I want to redirect to a URL that looks something like this

```
r'^user/(?P<id>\d+)/$'
```

The `<id>` is the primary key in the database...how do I go about this coz I'm stuck at this point

Comment: Are you asking how to put that in the <form action=""> field?

Comment: I'm more inclined to having the redirect at return HttpResponseRedirect('....')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in your .html file, you should have an action= in your form, which sort of looks like that regular expression. At the very least it should look something similar to:

```
action="/user/{{ object.id }}/"
```

object.id would be replaced with whatever object you passed to the html file in your view.

Comment: sweet...let me try that.  Thanks

Comment: seems like my view doesn't get the id at all...it just redirects to /user//

Comment: Are you redirecting to the page from one of your view functions using render_to_response? If so, you need to pass a dictionary of values. The object's id will need to be one of those.

Comment: think I've identified my problem...your solution should not work. Thnx

Comment: take the space out from between /user/ and {{ object.id }}.

Answer (score 1):

The url template tag allows you to save some repetition here. It also prevents you from breaking the form if you change urls.py. If your urlpattern looks like this:

```
(r'^user/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'user.views.detail')
```

Then you could use the template tag like this:

```
<form action="{% url user.views.detail object.id %}">
```